# How to print in one line in Python?

Tags: python, printing

```
import os
import time

loading = ["L", "O", "A", "D", "I", "N", "G"]
for i in range(3):
    os.system("cls")
    for a in  range(0,7):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(loading[a])
```

---> In the program Loading in going down-ways, I want it to be in a Line
I tried using `print(loading[a], end="")`
but it is just not working.

Comment: what does 'not working' mean?

Comment: What is the expect and actual output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted to do something like this:

```
import time

text = 'LOADING'
for n in range(3):
    print(f"\r{' '*len(text)}", end='')
    for i in  range(len(text)):
        message = text[:i+1]
        print(f"\r{message}", end='')
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

The trick is to add '\r' in front of the string you want to print.

Comment: `end=''` would be sufficient (assuming output is flushed); there's no need here to rewrite the entire string from the start of the line on each iteration.

Comment: @chepner I didn't get your comment. How would you do it?